# Throttle Laravel Exception email notification per Exception type

Tags: php, database, laravel, email, swiftmailer

Does anyone know of a way to throttle email notifications for a certain Exception in Laravel?

I made my app send me an email when there is a DB error by check for the `QueryException`. This is a rough example of what I did in Exception handler in Laravel:

```php
class Handler{

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * This is a great spot to send exceptions to Sentry, Bugsnag, etc.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $e)
    {
        if($e instanceof QueryException){

            if( App::environment(['production']) ){
                Notification::route('mail', 'myemail@test.com')
                            ->notify(new DbErrorNotification($e));
            }
        }

        parent::report($e);
    }

}
```

Short of tracking in DB, is there a way I could throttle DB errors by exception type so that I don't end up getting thousands of emails if there is a consistent DB error.

I looked at [Swift Mailer's anti-flood and throttling](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/plugins.html#antiflood-plugin) plugins but those affect the system globally which I don't want to do.

Thank you in advance

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62771954/4575350

Comment: One way is with a session for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a few way how you can achieve that. Right before dispatching a job you can add `delay` on it. Example:

```php
use App\Http\Request;
use App\Jobs\SendEmail;
use App\Mail\VerifyEmail;
use Carbon\Carbon;

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
 * @throws \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $baseDelay = json_encode(now());

    $getDelay = json_encode(
        cache('jobs.' . SendEmail::class, $baseDelay)
    );

    $setDelay = Carbon::parse(
        $getDelay->date
    )->addSeconds(10);

    cache([
        'jobs.' . SendEmail::class => json_encode($setDelay)
    ], 5);
    SendEmail::dispatch($user, new VerifyEmail($user))
         ->delay($setDelayTime);
}
```

Or if you don't like the idea about a job you can also delay it via `Mail`. Example:

```php
Mail::to($user)->later($setDelayTime);
```

And finally via Redis Rate Limiting. Example:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle()
{
    Redis::throttle('SendEmail')
        ->allow(1)
        ->every(10)
        ->then(function () {
            Mail::to($this->user)->send($this->mail);
        }, function () {
            return $this->release(10);
        });
}
```

> Allowing one email to be sent every ten seconds. The string SendEmail passed to the throttle() method is a name that uniquely identifies the type of job being rate-limited. You can set this to whatever you want.

> The release() method is an inherited member of your job class and
> instructs Laravel to release the job back onto the queue, with an
> optional delay in seconds, in the event a lock cannot be obtained.
> When the job is dispatched to the queue, Redis is instructed to only
> run one SendEmail job every ten seconds.

Keep in mind that for all of this you need a *Redis*

Source: https://medium.com/@bastones/a-simple-guide-to-queuing-mail-in-laravel-f4ff94cdaa59